# R equivalent of python's loc functionality

Tags: python, r

I would like to set the value of a row in an R dataframe. In python I would go

```
df.loc[2050,"Column1"] = 33
```

Somehow trying this in R is adding loads of rows to the dataframe. This is the code I have.

```
year_series <- c(2020,2030,2040,2050)
dfplot = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 4))
colnames(dfplot) <- c("Column1")
rownames(dfplot) <- year_series
dfplot[2050,"Column1"] <- 33
```

Comment: `dfplot[ rownames(dfplot) == 2050 ,"Column1"]  <- 33`

Comment: in your example the number refers to the 2050s row. Alternatively try `dfplot["2050","Column1"] <- 33` since `class(rownames(dfplot))` is *character*

Comment: Thank you @maydin and @Andre! both approaches worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're referencing the index 2050 and not the row with the name "2050". That's why you're seeing so many rows get added (up to 2,050 rows to be exact). What you will want to do is reference the row name "2050"

To state this via code/output if you ran:

```
dfplot$Column1[2050] <- 33
```

you would recieve the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Column1, value = c(NA, NA, NA, 33,  : 
  replacement has 2050 rows, data has 4
```

which is a helpful error code. The following code should run and give you the desired dataframe:

```
year_series <- c(2020,2030,2040,2050)
dfplot = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 4))
colnames(dfplot) <- c("Column1")
rownames(dfplot) <- year_series
dfplot["2050","Column1"] <- 33
```

It might be clearer and easier to add data later if you don't rename the rows. To run it that way:

```
year_df <- data.frame(year = c(2020,2030,2040,2050))
year_df$Column1 <- 'NA'
year_df[year_df$year == 2050,"Column1"] <- 33 #in this case year is a number and not a string
```